# How do graphing calculators like desmos generate their graphs?

Tags: plot, calculator, graphing

I was wondering how graphing calculators were able to plot functions and relations so quickly.

For a funtion, I can see just testing all the x values numerically in a domain, and outputting it that way. But how does this work for relations (such as x^2 + y^2 = 1)? Numerically testing every possible x and y value isn't that fast, as it would be O(n^2), right? How is it possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's based on the zoom, when you zoom in, you render the same amount of values. The graph only lets you see a max of 5 steps at a time so it doesn't check all the x values, it only checks the x values to the step*5. It also does not render the decimals like you would think. Instead of rendering x=x/100 to make the line look smooth, it does x=x/screenres. This means that like with 99% of graphics programs, it gets slower the higher your screen resolution is.